# How to get element number in a list?

Tags: elisp

**Q:** how do I get the element number in a list?

`nth` gets element number *n* from a list:

```
(nth 2 '(a b c d))                      ; => c
```

I'd like to do the reverse: get the element number given the element:

```
(some-function 'c '(a b c d))           ; => 2
```

I may have missed it, but does such a function exist?  How would one do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Here's a function that is included with Emacs 24.3 and later:

```lisp
(cl-position 2 '(6 7 8 2 3 4)) ;; => 3
```

(Before Emacs 24.3, use function `position` from library `cl.el`, which is included with Emacs.)

You can use the `:test` keyword to specify the comparison function:

```lisp
(cl-position "bar" '("foo" "bar" "baz") :test 'equal) ;; => 1
(cl-position '(1 2) '((3) (5 6) (1 2) nil) :test 'equal) ;; => 2
```

[Emacs Common Lisp Emulation Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/cl.html#Overview)

2. `dash.el` has a function that can do this: [`-elem-index`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-elem-index-elem-list)

```lisp
(-elem-index 2 '(6 7 8 2 3 4)) ;; => 3
(-elem-index "bar" '("foo" "bar" "baz")) ;; => 1
(-elem-index '(1 2) '((3) (5 6) (1 2) nil)) ;; => 2
```

It's not included with Emacs, but a lot of Emacs users already have it installed (it's a dependency of `projectile`, `flycheck`, and `smartparens`, which gives it a ton of coverage).

Answer (score 8):

Well, if you want to roll your own instead of using `cl-position`, and you don't want to traverse twice (using `length`)...

```el
(defun nth-elt (element xs)
  "Return zero-indexed position of ELEMENT in list XS, or nil if absent."
  (let ((idx  0))
    (catch 'nth-elt
      (dolist (x  xs)
        (when (equal element x) (throw 'nth-elt idx))
        (setq idx  (1+ idx)))
      nil)))
```

That's good for even old Emacs versions.  However, it has this behavior difference, which you might or might not want: It works also for the cars of a dotted list. That is, it correctly returns the position instead of raising an error, for sexps such as `(nth-elt 'c '(a b c . d))`.

If you want to always raise an error for an improper list, then you will want to check for that case, which requires always traversing to the end of the list:

```el
(defun nth-elt (element xs)
  "Return zero-indexed position of ELEMENT in list XS, or nil if absent."
  (let ((idx  0))
    (when (atom (cdr (last xs))) (error "Not a proper list"))
    (catch 'nth-elt
      (dolist (x  xs)
        (when (equal element x) (throw 'nth-elt idx))
        (setq idx  (1+ idx)))
      nil)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it's a simple function to write, although it may not be all that efficient:

```el
(defun nth-elt (elt list)
  "Return element number of ELT in LIST."
  (let ((loc (length (member elt list))))
    (unless (zerop loc)
      (- (length list) loc))))

(nth-elt 'c '(a b c d))                 ; => 2
(nth-elt 'f '(a b c d))                 ; => nil
```

I'd prefer a built-in solution if one exists, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer which uses simpler lisp-constructs than other answers here to step over the list (no throw/catch).

```el
(defun nth-elt (element xs)
  "Return zero-indexed position of ELEMENT in list XS, or nil if absent."
  (let ((index 0))
    (while (and xs (not (equal element (car xs))))
      (setq index (1+ index))
      (setq xs (cdr xs)))
    (and xs index)))
```

Examples:

```el
(nth-elt 2 '(6 7 8 2 3 4)) ;; => 3
(nth-elt "bar" '("foo" "bar" "baz")) ;; => 1
(nth-elt '(1 2) '((3) (5 6) (1 2) nil)) ;; => 2
(nth-elt 10 '(6 7 8 2 3 4)) ;; => nil
```

---

This is a version of the same function which takes an optional `:test` keyword argument.

This can be handy in practice when you may want to compare elements in a list or use a different comparison function.

```el
(defun nth-elt (element xs &rest args)
  "Return zero-indexed position of ELEMENT in list XS, or nil if absent.
Optional ARGS, may contain :test keyword argument,
it's value is used instead of `equal' for comparison,
where the first argument is always ELEMENT, the second is a member of XS."
  (let ((index 0)
        (test-fn (or (plist-get args :test) #'equal)))
    (while (and xs (not (funcall test-fn element (car xs))))
      (setq index (1+ index))
      (setq xs (cdr xs)))
    (and xs index)))
```